# Extract data from Table from CoinMarketCap

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Sorry in advance for not respecting any guidelines, it's my first post.

The issue is as follows:
I am building a screening bot for cryptocurrencies -  one of the steps is to get the exchanges a coin is listed on. I am planning to do this by scraping the table on the Market tab (i.e https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/valor-token/markets/ -> bithumb, ascendex and so on).

I've tried using BeautifulSoup with regex

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
table = soup.findAll("table", {"class" : re.compile('cmc-tab*')})

and 

def check_currency_markets(slug):
    url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/"+slug+"/markets"
    html_content = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml')
    print(soup.prettify())
    with open('sopa.txt', 'w') as fil:
        fil.write(str(soup.prettify()))
        fil.close()
```

and pandas

```
def check_currency_markets(slug):
    url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/"+slug+"/markets"
    dfs = pd.read_html(url)

    for df in dfs:
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(str(int(time.time()))+".xlsx")
        df.to_excel(writer)
        writer.save()
```

but none of them work. One thing I've observed when I use BeautifulSoup is that the string it returns does not contain any 'table' tag but it exists in the page's code.*

Could you, please, help me with a way of extracting that table of the page(or the list of the exchanges)?

*What can be the cause of this?

I know I can use the API for this, but I've spent quite a while trying to solve this and I'd really like to know the solution.

Edit: [Here](https://pastebin.com/31u0Z7UY) is what is returned by BeautifulSoup

Edit2: I've finally made it using Selenium. Now the string BeautifulSoup returns contains the elements I'm looking for and I can extract them.

```
def check_currency_markets(slug):
    url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/"+slug+"/markets"

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'chromedriver.exe')
    browser.get(url)

    html = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    
    print(soup.prettify())
    with open('sopa.txt', 'w') as fil:
        fil.write(str(soup.prettify()))
        fil.close()
```

Comment: Can you post the complete code? Makes it easier to reproduce errors and fix them.

Comment: What is returned by BeautifulSoup? I suspect that this has to do with the way/order in which things are loaded on the page. -- i.e. most likely javascript is rendering elements such as 'table' after the initial HTML document is loaded.

Comment: Checking quickly using the Chrome DevTools, this appears to be the case. You're going to have to do a little digging -- I know there are similar questions already on StackOverflow. This may be a challenge as I see the JavaScript on the page is obfuscated.